# Исторические корни слов

Tags: этимология

какое из слов исторически является однокоренным слову  ржавчина?
а)зараза;б)зардеться; в) заржать; г)оранжевый; д) ржаной

Answer (score 2):

б) зардеться
http://enc-dic.com/rusethy/Rzhav-3688.html

ржавый - суф. производное от rъža (> ржа после падения редуцированных),  от той же основы rъd-, что рдеть,руда.

Answer (score 1):

Предположительно - зардеться. Общее значение - красноватый (рыжеватый) оттенок. 
Зараза и заржать пропускаем, ничего общего, оранжевый бы отчасти скгодился, но это образование от имени собственного (герцоги Оранжские).  
Проверить сейчас не могу - очень тормозит Интернет.